# I can't find regex for my coding and code to insert that data to database

Tags: php, regex, curl, laravel-5.3

This is my code:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

$url = "https://www.bukalapak.com/p/fashion-pria/jam-tangan-171/8b1k0b-jual-jam-tangan-pria-skmei-original-model-casio-water-resistant-ps024?from=old-popular-section-1";
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

preg_match_all("!\"price\":[^\s]*?,!", $result, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);

curl_close($curl);
?>
```

This is the output:

[image]

I just want the nominal of price without `price`, but I don't know the regular expression for that.

Can you help me to insert that data (`$matches`) to my database? I tried this with XAMPP and phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. We can’t run your screenshot as code.

Comment: Maybe you need an HTML parser to extract the proper data.

Comment: oke. i will try. thi first to me. thanks @tadman

Comment: you just want the value "260000"?

Comment: or if you want to use regex: just put a capturing group `(...)` around the part you like to get and reference to it with `$matches[1]`

Comment: why downvote? this is valid question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all("!\"price\":([^\s]*?),!", $result, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Comment: A simplification: `([^\s]*?)` --> `(\S*)`

Comment: Thankyou so Much :)

Comment: but i try with this way

preg_match_all("!\"price\":([^\s]*?),!", $result, $matches);
$price['harga'] = $matches[1];
print_r($price['harga']);